# Conditional Rendering in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have a situation where I want to render a different header depending on the value of a variable in a Redux State.

*This is my MyClass.js*

```js
class MyClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            headerState: "home"
        };
        this.GetHeader = this.GetHeader.bind(this);
    }

    GetHeader() {
        const headerType = this.renderHeader;
        if (headerType == "a") {
            return (Some html code);
        } [...] {
            return (Some html code);
        } else {
            return (Some html code);
        }
    }

    render() { <
        GetHeader / > // This is line 79
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
        return {
            renderHeader: state.renderHeader
        };
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(MyClass));
```

*This is my reducer:*

```js
export default function renderHeaderReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'RENDER_HEADER':
            return [...state, Object.assign({}, action.headerType)];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

When I tried running the code, on the browser it says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GetHeader is not defined at Header.render (Header.js:79).

I followed this [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)(first example)

Not sure what I am doing wrong or what concepts I must have misunderstood in terms of binding methods to `this` context. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `GetHeader` variable, it's `this.GetHeader` method. There are no reasons to use `GetHeader` as React element, it's a method that doesn't need its own props. It doesn't need to be bound to `this` when called as a method.

There's no `this.renderHeader` because `renderHeader` is a prop.

It likely should be:

```
  state = {
    headerState: "home"
  }

  GetHeader() {
    const headerType = this.props.renderHeader;
    if (headerType == "a") {
       return (Some html code);
    } [...] {
      return (Some html code);
    } else {
      return (Some html code);
    }
 }

 render() {
   return <>
     {this.GetHeader()}
     ...
   </>;
 }
```

If `render` isn't too big or `GetHeader` isn't reused, there may be no need to extract its contents from `render`.

Comment: I get another error that says: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined. This is pointing to the `this.props.renderHeader.`

Comment: There shouldn't be such error if you use `GetHeader` as described in the answer, not as `<GetHeader>`.

Comment: Could you explain to me why it matters if i did {this.GetHeader()} versus <this.GetHeader() />? I am relatively new at this

Comment: `<this.GetHeader() />` is a mistake because it expects that `this.GetHeader()` returns React *component* (a class or a function). `<this.GetHeader/>` provides unneeded overhead because it wraps `GetHeader` function with `React.createElement`. you can't benefit from that in this case. `{this.GetHeader()}` inserts the layout that is returned from `GetHeader` into `render` layout.

Answer (score 0):

Because it isn't. You should add a variable in the render:

```
render() {
  const GetHeader = this.GetHeader;
  return <GetHeader />;
}
```

You code had 2 issues:
1. The GetHeader wasn't accessible locally.
2. You didn't use return statement

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missing function in front of GetHeader() {

```
function GetHeader(){}
```

For more reference check : https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html